# Is there a way to split only some <div> tags into two columns vertically?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Is there a way to split only particular divs into two columns? and in the ways that divs are aligned vertically.

My css file looks like following

```
#views-form
 {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#views-form .item-list {
  list-style-position: inside;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

But it results in spliting all divs inside of the form into two columns.

```
<form id="views-form">
   <div></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
    ....
   <div></div>
</form>
```

I need to split div tags with class "item-list" into two columns. Unfortuntely I am not able to wrap "item-list" divs in some other tag. I expect the dives to be aligned vertically. So that it looks like following:

```
<form>
 <div></div>
 <div class="item list"> 1 </div> | <div class="item list"> 4 </div>
 <div class="item list"> 2 </div> | <div class="item list"> 5 </div>
 <div class="item list"> 3 </div> | <div class="item list"> 6 </div>
 <div> </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To align those pairs at the same height as you stated in the comments, you can apply `display: flex` to the container and define the `width` of the flex-items as 50%, while having a set default setting of 100% for those DIVs in general, so that the other DIVs fill the whole container width:

```css
#views-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#views-form>div {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#views-form .item-list {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form id="views-form">
  <div>something</div>
  <div class="item-list"> some text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text  </div>
  <div class="item-list">  some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text </div>
  <div class="item-list">  some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text </div>
  <div class="item-list">  some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text </div>
  <div class="item-list">  some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text </div>
  <div class="item-list">  some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text </div>
  <div>something else </div>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry, I misread the question - changed my answer completely now.

Comment: It splits divs into two columns. But I am trying to reach a vertical alignment, rather than horizontal.

Comment: I added an example for my second solution

Comment: It works but it si aligning the divs horizontally like 1 | 2, 3 | 4,  5 | 6, but i need 1 | 4, 2 | 5, 3 | 6